# SSL_CRT_FILE is not found

Tags: reactjs, openssl, environment-variables, ssl-certificate

I've created a certificate file and private key file using openssl but the system can't find the CRT file.  I'm getting the following error:

> You specified SSL_CRT_FILE in your env, but the file "C:\Users\brohj\localhost.crt" can't be found.

Here is the .env file:

```
HTTPS=true
SSL_CRT_FILE=\Users\brohj\localhost.crt
SSL_KEY_FILE=\Users\brohj\localhost.key
```

The files are in that location.  I've also tried placing the files in the root of the app and I get the same error.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the 'file not found' issue by adding 'export' to the commands:

```
export HTTPS=true
export SSL_CRT_FILE=\Users\brohj\key\localhost.crt
export SSL_KEY_FILE=\Users\brohj\key\localhost.key
```

But I'm still getting the CORS browser error which is why I added the cert files in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when using ASP.NET Core (with react) using .NET 7.0.

I fixed it, by changing the username inside:

> `\ClientApp\.env.development.local`

There was an admin user to which I did not had access, so i changed the username to my currently logged in user, and everything works now!

also for reference, this is my debug profile:

[image]